# "La pasta mi piace al dente": origine di "al dente"

Tags: phrase-origin, cooking

La pasta lievemente indietro di cottura è più dura della pasta ben cotta, ma di qui a sostenere che sia dura come l'avorio ce ne passa.

Come mai la pasta lievemente indietro di cottura viene detta "al dente"?

Comment: Ti pare plausibile un'ellissi del tipo "(croccante) al dente"?

Comment: @Nico Mi sembra plausibile.

Comment: Forse potrebbe derivare da "esser sodo al dente" che appare [qui](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI04/00000196.jpg) e [qui](https://books.google.es/books?id=KvViaZoTKB4C&pg=PA381&lpg=PA381&dq=%22sodo+al+dente%22&source=bl&ots=EhZG62_Xop&sig=ACfU3U0Geyjz17Cok-_E--huvV5AwPtz1w&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwitmtv5o73oAhWnAGMBHX-sC60Q6AEwAXoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22sodo%20al%20dente%22&f=false).

Comment: A orecchio direi anch'io che il senso originario fosse che oppone una certa resistenza ai denti, non che sia dura come un dente.